# Rails form_for redirecting to different method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am working on a shopping cart app and have a order model. I added shipping details to my order model to include `carrier`, `tracking_number` and `ship_date`. I created a method called `updateshipping` in order to have a different redirect after updating the order.

I'm new to rails so not sure if possible to have a conditional redirect in rails after save, or if I should create a custom route to access the `updateshipping` method (what I tried), or if correct answer is that I should create a new model to hold the shipping details.

I tried to redirect the form partial to update via the method `updateshipping` but the submit button doesn't work. When I hover over the submit button the url doesn't appear. When I hit *Submit* it appears to reload the form partial.  If I remove everything after `@order` in the `form_for` it correctly goes to the update order/update method so I assuming my is issue is on the `form_for` line (or that is part of the order model in the first place.)

```
<%= form_for(@order, :url => shipment_path, :html => { :method => "put" }) do |f| %>

  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>

  <%= f.label :carrier %>
  <%= f.text_field :carrier %>

  <%= f.label :tracking_number, "Tracking #" %>
  <%= f.text_field :tracking_number %>

  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.submit "Save changes", class: "btn btn-warning" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Orders Controller

```
def updateshipping
  raise params.inspect  (code to update the order will come later)
end
```

Rake Routes

```
shipment        /shipmentdetails/:id(.:format)         orders#shipment_details
shipment PUT    /shipmentdetails/:id(.:format)         orders#updateshipping
```

routes.rb

```
match '/shipmentdetails/:id' => 'orders#shipment_details', :as => :shipment
match '/shipmentdetails/:id' => 'orders#updateshipping', :as => :shipment, via: :put
```

Orders Model

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :address, :carrier, :tracking_number, :ship_date
  has_many :line_items, dependent: :destroy
  has_one :user
  has_one :shop

  validates :name, :address, presence: true
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why this worked but I changed the route that linked to the form partial. I changed the route from:

```
match '/shipmentdetails/:id' => 'orders#shipment_details', :as => :shipment
```

to:

```
match '/shipmentdetails/:id/edit' => 'orders#shipment_details', :as => :edit_shipment
```

maybe it was getting confused between the shipment_path but I thought that the path from the form_for having  the "put" method it should have known to use the following route:

```
match '/shipmentdetails/:id' => 'orders#updateshipping', :as => :shipment, via: :put
```

As for the form_for from my original attempt

```
form_for(@order, :url => shipment_path, :html => { :method => "put" })
```

it seems to work just like the the recommended

```
form_for(@order, :url => shipment_path(@order), :html => { :method => "put" })
```

but I'm not sure if it's a better practice to use shipment_path(@order) instead of just shipment_path.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `:html => { :method => "put" }`, try `:method => "put"`

Comment: I tried this but same result. While testing, it appears the form partial reloads so it might not be recognizing the "put", issue with the match in the route.rb?

Answer (score 0):

change the form_for line into :

```
form_for(@order, :url => shipment_path(@order), :html => { :method => "put" })
```

Comment: I tried this but it didn't solve the issue by itself. I think the issue may have been confusion between the path for the edit and the update. Once I modified the route I was able to get it to work using the answer for the form for above as well as my original form_for. I'm not sure which is preferable.